# How do I set locked memory limit as unlimited on Google Colab?

Tags: linux, google-colaboratory, ubuntu-18.04, ulimit

Is it possible to expand locked memory limit on [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) notebooks? It runs on a Ubuntu 18.04 VM.

I'm running

```
ulimit -l unlimited
```

But I receive this in response

```
ulimit: max locked memory: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

This is what `ulimit -a` returns

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 51915
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1048576
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: What are you trying to do which requires a larger locked memory limit?

Comment: I'm trying to run jackd (JACK Audio Connection Kit) with a dummy soundcard.

This command basically: "jackd -d dummy"